# Jackson Already had POJO for id

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having trouble with the error: `Already had POJO for id` in my service.

I have a method that expects a list of entities, and I'm passing objects to it.

My entity class is defined as:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@asset_id", scope=Asset.class)
public class Asset extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
```

When I send the objects, I am sending them with all properties filled out but with no `@asset_id` defined.

When I get the list of items out of the db, it is like this:

`[{ "@actor_id": 1, "id": 1, "name": "Test" }]`

When I send it back, I send this

`[{ "id": 1, "name": "Test" }]`

Why am I getting this error?  If I leave the `@actor_id` in I get the error too.  I can't figure it out.

Comment: Change your property="@asset_id" to "@id" and see if it makes any diff

Comment: Do you have column "id" in your database?

Comment: Yes, I have an id property for the Asset class.

Answer (score 2):

`@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,property="@id", scope=Asset.class)`

This might solve your problem.